# If $3x^2+2\alpha xy+2y^2+2ax-4y+1$ can be resolved into two linear factors, prove that $\alpha$ is the root of the equation $x^2+4ax+2a^2+6=0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> If $3x^2+2\alpha xy+2y^2+2ax-4y+1$ can be resolved into two linear factors, prove that $\alpha$ is the root of the equation $x^2+4ax+2a^2+6=0$.

I know this question has already been asked on Math.SE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579571/if-3x2-2-alpha-xy-2y2-2ax-4y-1-can-be-resolved-into-two-linear-f/1579613), but is there a way to solve this by only using the concepts of quadratic equations? I am not very clear with the solution given there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discriminant of the equation $p(x,y) = 3x^2+(2\alpha y+2a)x +2y^2-4y+1=0$ is $\delta = (2\alpha y+2a)^2-12(2y^2+4y+1)$.

Thus, $$p(x,y) = 3\left(x-\frac{-(2\alpha y+a) +\sqrt{\delta}}{6}\right)\left(x-\frac{-(2\alpha y+a)-\sqrt{\delta}}{6}\right)$$

Now $p(x,y)$ is a perfect square iff the discriminant $\delta_1$ of $\delta =0$ is $0$. We can verify $\delta_1 =0 \Leftrightarrow \cdots \Leftrightarrow \alpha^{2}+4\alpha a+ 2a^2+6=0$. Equivalently, $\alpha$ is a root of $x^2+4ax+2a^2+6=0$.

Comment: $\delta =0$ is one way for $\delta$ to be a perfect square. What about other solutions? $\alpha$might not be the solution of that equation in those other cases...

Comment: Isn't that the only case? What do you mean by other solutions?

Comment: How do we know $\delta=0$?

Comment: Actually, we are factoring the polynomial p(x,y) using its discriminant . Now, we should have $\delta=0$ for it(the discriminant of p(x,y)) to be a perfect square. This gives us the required condition. Also, very simply, without all the fuss, the problem is equivalent to finding where the given conic is degenerated. As p(x,y) is a conic in general form.

Comment: Oh do you mean p(x,y) is a perfect square instead of $\delta$ is a perfect square...

Comment: Yes, you got the point of the question.

Comment: why p(x,y) has to be a perfect square for it to be factorize into linear factors?